# How do you set placeholder text in a TextField to italics?

Tags: ios, swiftui

We can set italics on `Text` with the `.italic()` modifier, but how would you set italics in a `TextField` View for the placeholder text?

```swift
struct TextFieldItalics: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .italic()
            TextField("Add username", text: $username)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With font modifier:

```
.font(Font.body.italic())
```

Comment: amazing! So many small things to learn. Thank you for point it out @swiftPunk